# Eclipse LUNA and importing existing Maven project

Tags: maven

When I import project maven (Guestbook project in JAVA Tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code), show the following problem:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-war-plugin: 2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-war- plugin: jar: 2.4
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-war-plugin: 2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-war-plugin: jar: 2.4

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked to build the project on command line without any issue?

Comment: Yes, maven commands work well on the command line. But within Eclipse does not work. I even tried creating the project itself again from Eclipse (New maven Project) shows the same error.

Comment: The error message look like some network/proxy problems...which is unrelated to Eclipse or Maven.